# How to Customize navigation bar in XCode5 iOS7 in AppDelegate file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to customise the navigation bar of my iPhone app. I want to add an image in the left side of the navigation bar title. 
I tried the following code from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the AppDelegate.m file:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 10, 20, 20)];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    [myView addSubview:image];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:myView];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView=myView;
```

but it doesn't work. When I try it from the `viewDidLoad` of one of my ViewControllers it works. But i want to inherit this behaviour in all my ViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationItem has a property, titleView. You need to set that to your custom view, and then that view will replace the standard title (so you need to have your image and a label for the title in your custom view).

Comment: @user3107262, If it didn't work, then you did it incorrectly. Also "didn't work" is useless for diagnosing your problem. What did it do specifically? Update you question with the code you tried using the titleView property.

Comment: @user3107262, the navigationItem belongs to each controller, not the navigation controller, so if you want to have your custom view be used in all your controllers, then you should have a base controller class that implements that, and have your other controllers inherit form that base class. You also need to take out the line where you add myView as a subview. Also, your custom view will need a label for the title if you want both an image an some text.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = myView;
```